# Update variable based on button press

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, switch-statement

I have a small iOS program in `Swift` that lists restaurants and user ratings. I created a Restaurant class, and stored data in an array as such

```
Restaurant(name: "Example", type: "Coffee & Tea Shop", location: "Example Town, NY", phoneNumber: "232-923423", image: "example.jpg", isVisited: false, ratingSave: "")
```

I assigned tags to three button objects

```
@IBAction func ratingSelected(sender: UIButton) {
    switch (sender.tag) {
    case 100: rating = "dislike"
    case 200: rating = "good"
    case 300: rating = "great"
    default: break
}
```

My issue is that whenever the user leaves the screen to provide a rating, the rating disappears. I added the variable ratingSave to my class, and I want that variable to update to one of the three tags (or the strings I assigned the tags to). I also want isVisited to update to true when a rating is applied as well. How would I do that?

Comment: You need a reference to the current `Restaurant` instance, the restaurant which is going to be rated at the moment and change the property `ratingSave` accordingly. `isVisited` could be a computed property `!ratingSave.isEmpty`.

Comment: Don't use the `tag` property on views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Don't use tags

You have three buttons for each of the different ratings...

So create three actions. One for each button.

```
@IBAction func dislikeSelected() {
    rating = "dislike"
}

@IBAction func goodSelected() {
    rating = "good"
}

@IBAction func greatSelected() {
    rating = "great"
}
```

Because you are no longer using the button at all you can remove the input parameter.

Now you don't have to worry about the tags at all.

## Saving the rating

In order to "save" the rating you need to pass the restaurant in as a property and then update it...

```
var restaurant: Restaurant?
```

Now for your update methods...

```
@IBAction func dislikeSelected() {
    guard let selectedRestaurant = restaurant else {return}

    selectedRestaurant.rating = "dislike"
}
```

## Use enums :D

As @Abizern said, the `rating` property would be much better as an enum rather than just strings.

Inside your restaurant file you can define it like...

```
enum Rating {
    case None
    case Dislike
    case Good
    case Great
}
```

And change the type of the `rating` property from `String` to `Rating`.

Now in your rating function you can have...

```
@IBAction func dislikeSelected() {
    guard let selectedRestaurant = restaurant else {return}

    selectedRestaurant.rating = Rating.Dislike
}
```

Comment: @Abizern hahaha! True.

Comment: I think the rating is better expressed as an enum rather than just passing strings around.

Comment: @Abizern oh absolutely :) Only did that because of the OP's question. Will update answer though.

Comment: Thank you both! I'm really new to programming, you've helped me a lot.

Comment: @pyogen happy to help. There is an ebook available through iTunes made by Apple. It's free and is an excellent intro to swift. You should read that.